# Need help decimating obj, from a CAD program

Tags: mesh, topology, retopology, remesh

Im semi experienced in blender and have been running into a issue with rendering. Ive created this generative object made in NTOP. This object will be 3d printed with original STL file. But im looking on importing it to blender to animate it with video, the problem is i need 13 more of these objects in the scene. and one object is 330k faces. ive tried low poly and sub division surface on top, but the topology geometry is messed up. ive also used instant meshes program to remesh, and a little unsuccessful in that.

the object is not modeled, its an action used in the cad softeware to make the object with less material as possible with certain mathematical force points. (topology optimization) so after preforming the action in NTOP the mesh is not ideal to put into blenders way of computing. similar to a photoscan. ive seen people get away with remeshing phot scans for game assets but im looking to get macro video clips and photos of the product.

is this a dead-end on my blender skills? probably. is there a fix? or do i need to remodel it in blender (doesnt need to be 100% accurate) [image: most successful remesh from InstantMesh with subdivison surface applied to shoe mesh mistakes (black "dots")]

[image: mesh mistakes from InstantMesh In rendered view, Just need those smooth]